# JQuery UI Theme Problem

Tags: jquery

This shouldn't be so hard but I just can't seem to get this to work. Just trying to use a dialog box but can't get it to format the theme.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Demo</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="flora.all.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="Flora (Default)" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui/jquery.ui.all.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    $(function () {
        $('#test').dialog();
    });
    //-->
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="test"> This is a dialog. </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I missing? The css are at the base level and I can see them in firebug but nothing in the dialog is formated to look like the what I see in the demo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example the div has class 'flora' -- have you tried applying that class to your div to see if that helps?  Also, you need to run your function on document ready -- right now, I don't think it is running at all.

```
 $(document).ready( function() {
    $('#test').dialog();
 });
```